# How to change window level of an image on canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have an image on canvas or a set of images that i draw on the canvas. I can draw them fine but I want to change the window level of the image on canvas by dragging the mouse over it. I've seen a lot of external javascript api's but they're quite huge and i don't want to use them for this purpose.

here's my [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1vgfcttd/) that is basically drawing an image on the canvas

this is how my code looks

```
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample5_l.jpg";
```

i need something with basic JS or JQuery. it would be great if you can point me in the right direction using a sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at CSS3 animation: use absolute positioning, and change left and top values.

Comment: How would changing the x and y values of the positioning change the window/level of the image display?

Comment: you can have a look at this @RJM. https://jsfiddle.net/ivmartel/kkp7ytk3/ this is basically doing it using x and y values internally. but this is a library that i don't want to use. i just want a plain javascript or a jquery solution.

Comment: @ArifBurhan I am only looking for a javascript or a Jquery solution. i would want my users to change the window level on the image themselves rather than doing it automatically. so CSS3 is not an option here.

Comment: so you want us to write a library smaller than the ones existing? I don't know how to make a window/level filter, but you will need to `ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)` in order to have all your pixels, then do the processing on every pixel, which are stored in an array and divided by rgba values, then `putImageData(the_modified_imageData, 0,0)`.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido. i dont want you to write the library. i just want you guys to point me in the right direction as to how i can do something similar without using a library with its overheads.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I gained after some research:

```
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const rangeMin = level - window / 2;
const rangeMax = level + window / 2;

const totalSize = canvas.width * canvas.height;

for (let idx = 0; idx < totalSize; idx++) {
    if (imageData.data[idx] < rangeMin) {
        imageData.data[idx] = 0;
    } else if (imageData.data[idx] > rangeMax) {
        imageData.data[idx] = 255;
    }
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use JavaScript, try something like:

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("drawingboard");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var mouseDown = 0;
document.body.ontouchstart = function() { 
mouseDown+=1;
}
document.body.ontouchend = function() {
mouseDown-=1;
}
function draw(event){
ctx.color='gold';
ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
ctx.drawImage(img,event.clientX,event.clientY);}
</script>
```

Comment: how is this going to change the window level of the image?

Comment: A new image will be drawn where the mouse is clicked, you might want to erase the original image with a blank rectangle.

Comment: The question isn't about how to move the image.  It's about window/level.